# how to get list of an specific image likers in instagram?

Tags: php, api, instagram

for example my instagram account is "A" and i have an image on  account "B".
can i get a list of likers of the image on account "B" with account "A".
(All works such as authentication and all thing about instagram api is done on account "A").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with public API you can get latest 120 likes of any public user's post.

You need to have `public_content` permission scope and use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```